# Issue with building an Angular 2 RC router link with a route parameter

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am in reference to Angular 2 documentation about the RC router **route parameters**:

Here is what is mentioned in the documentation about constructing a router link with a route parameter:

```
['HeroDetail', { id: hero.id }] // {id: 15}
```

This is supposed to produce the following link:

```
localhost:3000/hero/15
```

I have the following link:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/dashboard/messageconversation/', {otherId: getOther(message).id}]">
```

and it produces the following link (notice the **semicolon** as well as the **query parameter** instead of the **route parameter**):

```
http://localhost:8080/dashboard/messageconversation;otherId=2
```

Here is the `@Routes` definition:

```
{path: '/messageconversation/:otherId', component: MessageConversationComponent}
```

Can anyone please tell me what I am getting wrong?

Comment: I hit this today and found the answer in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37285595/nested-routes-in-angular-2-with-release-candidate-component-router

Comment: Spot on! It works fine. Thanks a lot @stuntbaboon .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out the proper way to add a **route parameter** (as opposed to **query parameter**) is to pass the parameter as the second element of the array as follows:

```
<a [routerLink]="['/dashboard/messageconversation', getOther(message).id]">
```

*Credits go to stuntbaboon for directing me to the relevant post.*